# Wordpress shortcode not working on pages, but working on posts

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I've got an issue that's driving me a bit mad.

I'm working with a child theme on Wordpress and somewhere along the way, shortcode has stopped working on pages. The code itself does not appear on the page; in fact, it seems to "break" the page entirely, as no text or images placed in the page with the shortcode appear either. Other pages (ones without shortcode) are working fine. Shortcode is working fine in posts, as well.

If I switch back to the parent theme, the shortcode works fine everywhere.

So, I'm assuming that this has something to do with code I've written for the child theme. I've mainly been working with the style.css and home.php files, and just recently created a page template that I applied to one page on the site. I've been over and over the css and can't seem to find anything that might be causing this. Any ideas?

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: provide codes you written

Answer (score 1):

How is the content called in your page.php?

Maybe it helps, if you wrap it with *do_shortcode()* arround it, so the call will become

> do_shortcode(get_the_content())

for example.

Comment: This helped me. Only thing I had to add was echo. So: `echo do_shortcode(get_the_content());`